# Generic/Text Printer on Windows 7 not prompting for file name

Tags: windows-7, terminal, printing, emulator

Hope someone can shed some light on this.

I am downloading reports from an AIX-based system by directing them to a TT printer which the terminal emulator (MultiView 2000) intercepts and directs to the default printer on the local system. This local printer is configured as a vanilla Generic/Text printer attached to a FILE port. When I print from AIX, the output is spooled down and the local printer prompts for a file name into which to save the file...but not under Windows 7.

This has worked fine for many years, on both Win2K and WinXP. However, on Windows 7 the output gets spooled as a file into spool\PRINTERS (and looks as expected) but the print job then hangs with a status of "Error - Printing" and never prompts for a file name. I have to cancel the job.

The Generic/Text printer works as expected with other applications. I have tried setting the printer to print directly rather than spooling but this only serves to hang the terminal session too.

I've also tried to run the emulator in Windows 2000 Compatibility Mode and as Administrator in case it was something like that but with no luck. As you might expect, it does work fine in XP Mode (as long as I print to a printer defined therein and not the host's printer) but operationally this isn't going to be an option.

Obviously this emulation software is a decade old (at least) and I could just cross/upgrade all the users (at a cost) but, before I do so, has anyone seen this sort of behaviour before and found some sort of fix?

Remote OS: AIX 5
Client OS: Windows 7 Pro (32-bit)
Printer: Generic/Text on a FILE port
TE Software: MultiView 2000 (32-bit)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Open Add a local printer
select port "FILE:"
go to Next ; now the Generic printer is available
Select Generic + Generic / Text only